# Modify file in memory while keeping directory

Tags: bash, sed

Is there a way to modify the contents of a file before a command receives it while maintaining its directory?

```
mpv 'https://example.com/directory/file.playlist'
```

but use `sed` to modify the contents in memory before it is read by `mpv`?

The issue is I can't just read the file straight in, it must maintain the directory it is in because the files in the playlist are relative to that directory.

[I just need to replace `.wav` with `.flac`](https://gist.github.com/maletor/5aef103e17693b7af13c).

Comment: A remote file also doesn't have a "directory" that means anything locally. What does the file actually contain and what do you need to make it contain?

Comment: Can you post a sample of the file? How can you play the individual songs from the command line?

Comment: I added a sample file.

Comment: I'm not using Linux at the moment so I can't test a proper answer to this question, however I believe that mplayer is capable of reading from stdin and there may be some clues on this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55247/mplayer-controls-when-using-stdin-playlists

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can use [*process substitution*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
mplayer <(curl 'http://...' | sed 's/\.wav/.flac/')
```

However, `mplayer` supports the special option `-` (hyphen) for the filename argument which means *read the file from stdin*. This allows you to use a pipe:

```
curl 'http://...' | sed 's/\.wav/.flac/' | mplayer -
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you! I'm also looking at the `=(...)` in `zsh`.

Comment: Check out [this page of the documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_7.html) and the last paragraph. It won't fit in a comment box.

Comment: Also, `sed` requires an ending `g` for the substitution to work, but that's obviously not important to the question above.

Comment: Ok, got `=(...)`. I would go for the pipe option in this case. This works with all shells. About `sed`, The `g` option for the `s` command is required only if you want to replace multiple occurrences *per line*(!). `.wav` appears just once per line. That's why I've omitted `g`

Comment: Uh oh, [looks like it doesn't work](https://gist.github.com/maletor/5aef103e17693b7af13c#gistcomment-1629250).

Comment: It tells `Failed to open ./01 - Natural Mystic.flac. Could not open source './01 - Natural Mystic.flac'!` <<< That's the problem. This is not related to the way I've suggested call it. It actually means that `.way` has been successfully replaced by `.flac` but the audio files are not present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96065/discussion-between-maletor-and-hek2mgl).

Answer (score 0):

So far I'm using this to achieve what I need, but it's not exactly ideal in that I lose my playlist control.

`ssh example.com "tar czpf - 'files/super awesome music directory'" | tar xzpf - -O | mpv -`